# 逆から総和を求めるプログラムが上手くいきません

Tags: vba, ms-access

X～Yまでの総和を求めるプログラムを作りたいです。逆から求めるプログラムも作らなければいけません。Exit Sub は使えません。大きい数から小さい数を求める際に反応しません。どうしたらいいですか？
2つのテキストボックスに数を入力して、3つ目のテキストボックスに総和を表示させたいです。

**Access VBA**

```
Private Sub btnWa_Click()
   
Dim lX As Long
Dim lY As Long
Dim lS As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lSouwa As Long

lX = txtX.Value
lY = txtY.Value

If lX > lY Then
　　　　　lS = -1
Else: lS = 1

lSouwa = 0

For i = lX To lY Step lS
     lSouwa = lSouwa + i
Next i

txtSouwa.Value = lSouwa

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
If 条件 Then
    条件が真のときの処理
Else
    条件が偽のときの処理
End If
```

IF文は上記のように条件分岐を行うので、
lX > lYの場合、lS = -1のみが実行され
その他の場合は、ElseからEnd Ifまでの処理が実行されます。

lSの値を設定するための条件分岐であれば
Else: lS = 1の次の行にEnd Ifを移動すればよいと思います。

Comment: そういう発想がありませんでした。ありがとうございました。